# How to point elements childrens with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have little problem with element childrens.

Heres some code to explain my question:

```
function check(element){
    // I want to get custom attribute from element children. 
    // Children elements are always radio buttons
    var temp = element. ?? .attr('temp');
    return temp;
    }

 // element variable is the whole div here
    <div id = "test">
     <table>
       <tr>
         <td> <input type="radio" temp="somethinghere"/></td>
       </tr>
     </table>
    </div>
```

Hope someone has ideas or even better.. solution.

Comment: What do you want to do when there are multiple children?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
function check(element) {
    var ret = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++) {
        if (element.childNodes[i].type == 'radio') {
            ret.push(element.childNodes[i].getAttribute('temp'));
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```

This will return an array containing all the `temp` attributes of the radio children of the element.

Comment: Thanks you very much! This did the trick. there's just one ')' missing at the 'temp'); :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var temp = element.getAttribute('temp')
```

Or

```
var temp = element.temp = temp;
```

Or

```
var temp = element['temp'] = temp;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getAttribute

Edit: try:

```
var temp = '';
for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes; i++)
    temp += element.childNodes[i].getAttribute('temp');
return temp;
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Nope. I need to access this element childrens and get those attributes. I just don't know how to access them.

Answer (score 0):

To get an array of all the children of element :

```
element.childNodes;
```

To get an array of all input tags that are descendants of element :

```
element.getElementsByTagName("input")
```

Then loop through either of those arrays.

Answer (score -1):

try this for the first child radio button

```
var temp = element.children(':radio:first').attr('temp');
```

of if you want all 'temp' attr from all child radio button do following:

```
var arrTemp = element.children(':radio').map(function(){
    return $(this).attr('temp'); 
    // or you can make it more detail like:
    // return { ID: $(this).attr('id'), Temp: $(this).attr('temp') };
}).get();
```

**UPDATE** for table sample

```
var arrTemp = element.find(':radio').map(function(){
        return $(this).attr('temp'); 
        // or you can make it more detail like:
        // return { ID: $(this).attr('id'), Temp: $(this).attr('temp') };
    }).get();
```

Comment: This is assuming jQuery, btw Children elements are _always_ radio buttons

Comment: I don't think he asked for jquery